# How do I/should I split my react integration test?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this test which does 3 things:

1. input onChange gets updated
2. button onClick fires searchMovies request with input value
3. Results are in the document

test code:

```
import { searchMovies as mockSearchMovies, getPopular, getFiltered, getGenreIds } from "./tmdbAPI"

 afterEach(cleanup)

jest.mock('./tmdbAPI', () => {
  return {
    searchMovies: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{ id: 1, title: "test-1", poster_path: 'test-path' }])),
    getPopular: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{}])),
    getFiltered: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{}])),
    getGenreIds: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{}])),
  }
})

test('1. input onChange gets updated, 2. button onClick fires searchMovies request with input value, 3. Results are in the document', async () => {
  const { debug, getByPlaceholderText, getByTestId } = render(
    <Provider>
      <FindMovies />
    </Provider>
  )
  const testText = 'some movie title'
  const input = getByPlaceholderText('Search movies...')
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: testText } })
  expect(input.value).toBe(testText)

  const button = getByTestId('search-button')
  fireEvent.click(button)
  expect(mockSearchMovies).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(mockSearchMovies).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testText)

  await wait(() => expect(getByTestId("found-movie-item")).toBeInTheDocument())
})
```

1. How do I/should I split this test so each `test` keeps it's "state" so I can move on next one?
2. I'm running useEffect function in my provider which runs `getPopular`, `getFiltered` and `getGenreIds` async request. If I'm not mocking them as in example above I get an error. Is there a way to get around these unnecessary mocks that I'm currently not testing?

Comment: Why do you want to split the test? I would keep it as it is.

Comment: I don't know. I'm new to testing. Not sure what is the best practices

Comment: What I do is to test a feature or a user interaction. That's what you're test is doing, you're testing a complete feature from start to finish. I wouldn't change it personally